# REST resource for specified content type

Tags: 8

Drupal 8 has a REST resource for all content type "Content" and let us to specified settings for all of content type in `admin/config/services/rest/resource/entity%3Anode/edit` ,but is globally, I mean if let users post data to Content type, they can Post data to all of  content types  and(But what I need is I don't let them to do this), I didn't find any option to restrict to specified content type.
[image]

I also take a look at permission and  RESTful Web Services permission is for "Access POST on Content resource" and there is not any option for content types individually.
[image]

I want to know how can achieve this that REST POST feature exists for specified content type(s) and for some content type GET exists and for some content type REST not allowed?

**Update**(more deatils about what I want)
**I want anonymous user can POST  contenttype1 content with REST** ,
I give permission to anonymous user to  create contenttype1 content, and 
Authentication providers`section I check`cookie`and`basic_auth`  methods, but when try to post data with following code it told me authentication required 
(I ran this snippet  in browser console )

```
(function($){

                    jQuery.ajax({
                        url: '/rest/session/token',
                        method: 'GET',
                        success: function (token, status, xhr) {
                            var postData = {}
                            postData.title = [{'value': 'My Basic Page'}];
                            postData.field_enroll_email = [{'value': 'zhilevan@gmail.com'}];
                            postData.type = 'enroll';
                            jQuery.ajax({
                                url: "/entity/node",
                                method: "POST",
                                data: JSON.stringify(postData),
                                headers: {"Accept": "application/json", "X-CSRF-Token": token, "Content-Type": "application/json"},
                                success: function (data, status, xhr) {
                                    console.log(data);
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    });
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I mean if let users **post** data to Content type, they can Post data to
>   all of my content types and I didn't find any option to restrict to
>   specified content type.

Doesn't `/admin/people/permissions` stop them?

**Permission**

- Basic page: Create new content
- Article:  Create new content

> and for some content type GET exists

Don't you have to create a views rest export first before data is available to GET?

You can restrict here by adding a filter of `type` to your view.

Comment: Thanks for attention, But I think  I didn't explain well and you misunderstand,  when told POST I mean REST POST.

Comment: @zhilevan I understood you correctly. Do user role permissions not apply to REST? Have you tested with a user that is not super admin (user/1)

Comment: I didn't try but I dont want users can use content edit/create form, I only want they can create by REST ( only in mobile application and not in site). ( although it is not hard for me to prevent user access content edit/create form ( specified role(s) I mean). I try that and inform you. tnx for your note

Comment: What you're asking now seems like a different question. You can definitely give create permission only for a specific type and then both REST and the UI will respect that. If you want to allow *only* REST then you will need to think of something else and e.g. alter the routes for the forms.

Comment: @Berdir no,I asked a question, I want anonymous user can post data to contenttype1 with REST.

Comment: @NoSssweat not work. I update the question with more details about what I want.

Comment: @zhilevan IMO your update should be a separate question, since it's different than your initial question. Anyhow, I don't know of a way, all I know is that cookie or basic auth are required. I've never used cookie, so idk how that works. So it appears the only way would be to hack core to allow you to use REST without basic auth or cookie.

Comment: @NoSssweat you mean  anonymous user can not submit content with POST REST api?

Comment: @zhilevan with the Core Services module, I am afraid not. You should look into the **contrib** [Services](https://www.drupal.org/project/services) module, maybe that one will allow you? idk, I've never used that one before.

Comment: @NoSssweat I am in drupal 8.

Comment: @zhilevan I am well aware of that, there is an 8.x-4.0-alpha4 version.

Comment: @NoSssweat Maybe I should write Custom Service Resource , I am not pro developer in Drupal 8 yet :(

Comment: @NoSssweat Thanks a lot, I ask another question here, this link is about how to get ( maybe the solution can help me about POST too).tnx